# Bind Switch to scalar property of OData entity

Tags: odata, sapui5

I want to bind a Switch to a scalar property `CONFIG_VALUE` of an OData entity named `CONFIG`. My current try is as follows (where 3 is the key):

```
<Switch state="{CONFIG(3)/?$select=CONFIG_VALUE}"/>
```

But I think, this ODataModel always returns an object instead of a single value and the switch is always false.

My `xsodata` file looks like this, I simply expose a table:

```
  service {
    "schema::config" as "CONFIG";
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

By using `$select` you tell the OData service to return only a subset of properties. It does not mean that you get only the value of a specified property. That means you still need to refer to the property in your binding.

In your case it would look like this:

```
<Switch state="{
    path:'CONFIG(3)/CONFIG_VALUE', 
    parameters: { 
        $select : 'CONFIG_VALUE'
    }
}"/>
```